# Binding a json array with combobox

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am getting a json array string as response from a page. I want to bind it with a combobox.

This is the success block which gives me the json array string:

The json array string looks like this:

[image: messagebox displaying the json array string]

Please let me know hoe to bind this with the combobox drop down.

Regards,

**EDIT:**

This is the latest code I tried:

```
Ext.define('Country',{
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
    { name: 'id', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'name', type: 'string' }
]
});

Ext.define('CountryCombo', {
extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
alias: 'widget.countrycombo',
allowBlank: false,
queryMode: 'local',
valueField: 'id',
displayField: 'name',
store: {
    model: 'Country',
    data: [
        { id: 'China', name: 'China'},
        { id: 'Japan', name: 'Japan'},
        { id: 'Malaysia', name: 'Malaysia'}
    ]
},
listeners: {
    "select": function(obj){  
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: '/CellEditing/FormServlet',
            method: 'POST',
            params: {
                data: obj.getValue()
            },
            success: function(obj){
                alert('success');
                alert(obj.responseText);
                console.log(StateCombo.storeStates); //This is undefined hence getting error
                StateCombo.storeStates.loadData(obj.responseText);
            },
            failure: function(obj){
                alert('failure');
            }
        });                 
    }
}
});

var storeStates = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
autoLoad: false,
fields: ['State']
});

Ext.define('State',{
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
    { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
    { name: 'name', type: 'string' }
]
});

Ext.define('StateCombo', {
extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
alias: 'widget.statecombo',
queryMode: 'local',
valueField: 'State',
displayField: 'State',
store: storeStates
});
```

This is the latest I tried but still when I select something from 1st combobox, the second combobox is not getting populated.  any Help on this please?

Comment: What is the reason you're doing a separate ajax request and then putting the data in the store? Why not just use the store directly to load the data?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I changed the above posted code in EDIT section. It is also not working. Please let me know what am I missing in the store\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically this code will work:

http://jsfiddle.net/sdt6585/wPzPD/29/

```
Ext.define('Country',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'name', type: 'string' }
    ]
});

Ext.define('CountryCombo', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    alias: 'widget.countrycombo',
    allowBlank: false,
    queryMode: 'local',
    valueField: 'id',
    displayField: 'name',
    store: {
        model: 'Country',
        data: [
            { id: 'China', name: 'China'},
            { id: 'Japan', name: 'Japan'},
            { id: 'Malaysia', name: 'Malaysia'}
        ]
    },
    listeners: {
        "select": function(obj){
            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: '/CellEditing/FormServlet',
                method: 'POST',
                params: {
                    data: obj.getValue()
                },
                callback: function (response, operation) {
                    //This should be the text string in reponseText, just putting it there since I don't have it
                    response.responseText = '{data: [{state: "State One"}, {state: "State Two"}, {state: "State Three"}]}'
                    //Put this in your success function
                    var data = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText).data;
                    storeStates.loadData(data);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});

var storeStates = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad: false,
    fields: ['state']
});

Ext.define('State',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'name', type: 'string' }
    ]
});

Ext.define('StateCombo', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    alias: 'widget.statecombo',
    queryMode: 'local',
    valueField: 'state',
    displayField: 'state',
    store: storeStates
});

Ext.form.Panel.create({
    title: 'Tester',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [
        CountryCombo.create(),
        StateCombo.create()
    ]
});​
```

The major changes are these:

- You need to decode the json string you got back with Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText)) in the success function of your ajax call
- You defined a state model, but the state store didn't use it.  It can be removed.
- You had the state variable capitalized everywhere except in your json string.  Corrected it to lower case.
- Your reference to state combo was only to the template class for that view, not to an instance of it.  In addition, if it were an initialized class, it's store property is defined as such and has nothing to do with your variable name.  You can either store a reference to the created combo box and call it's store properties loadData function, or like I did, just use the storeStates reference to the store to load the data.

While that technically works, it's not the most elegant solution.  You would be working with much more maintainable code to follow this process.

1. Define Models for Country and State (ideally not in the global namespace!!) and give the state store a proxy to automatically decode the json responses.
2. Define stores that use the models as their base
3. Define views for your combo boxes (only if they will be reused elsewhere)
4. Put instances of the combo boxes in a container of some sort (use either Ext.create() or the create() function of your view classes.
5. Attach a listener to the instance of the country combo that you have created and have it call the load function of stateCombo's store.

---

```
Ext.define('MyApp.models.Country',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    requires: ['Ext.data.SequentialIdGenerator'],
    idgen: 'sequential',
    fields: [
        { name: 'name', type: 'string' }
    ]
});

Ext.define('MyApp.stores.Country', {
    model: 'MyApp.models.Country',
    data: [
        { name: 'China'},
        { name: 'Japan'},
        { name: 'Malaysia'}
    ]
});

Ext.define('MyApp.models.State',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    requires: ['Ext.data.SequentialIdGenerator'],
    idgen: 'sequential',
    fields: [
        { name: 'state', type: 'string' }
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        method: 'post',
        url: '/CellEditing/FormServlet',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data',
            successProperty: false
        }
    }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.stores.State', {
    model: MyApp.models.State
});

Ext.define('MyApp.views.CountryCombo', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    alias: 'widget.countrycombo',
    allowBlank: false,
    queryMode: 'local',
    valueField: 'name',
    displayField: 'name',
    store: MyApp.stores.Country.create()
});

Ext.define('MyApp.views.StateCombo', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    alias: 'widget.statecombo',
    queryMode: 'local',
    valueField: 'state',
    displayField: 'state',
    store: MyApp.stores.State.create()
});

Ext.form.Panel.create({
    title: 'Tester',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [
        countryCombo = MyApp.views.CountryCombo.create(),
        stateCombo = MyApp.views.StateCombo.create()
    ]
});

countryCombo.on('beforeselect', function (combo, record, index, eOpts) {
    stateCombo.store.load({
        params: {data: record.get('name')}
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for the description and the alternative, it really helped a lot. But I am having a issue with the callback response.responseText. When I put `alert(response.responseText)` it is coming as undefined. Again, If I use the success rather than using callback, then the suggestions you mentioned works perfectly. Why is this problem happening with callback? And why do you prefer callback over success inside the ajax request? Please explain.

Comment: Short answer is that the parameters for callback (options, success, response) are different than the parameters for success (response, options).

About why I would prefer callback over success, I only used it to get it to work on the jsfiddle link.  Callback is called regardless of whether or not the request was successful and I didn't have access to your web service. Success is only called when a 400/OK header is received and the success property (if set) is true.  Check the docs: [link](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Connection-method-request)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. One last doubt before closing this bounty threar: Why is the response.responseText returning undefined? IT is working perfectly when I use success. Any idea on that?

Comment: Post the method signature for your success and callback functions.  I'm guessing that you are defining them with the variables in the same order.  It should be:
success: function (response, options) {/*code*/}
     and
callback: function (options, success, response) {/*code*/}
If you're looking at the first variable in the callback, it won't have a response text property, but the third will.  And javascript doesn't do named parameters so the order is the key, not the names.

Comment: That was my fault, I didn't check the docs before posting that code and it didn't matter because I set the responseText property myself to emulate the response without the web service.  Change the callback signature to: 

callback: function (options, success, response) {}, and you should be set to use response in callback if you want.  Success is probably more appropriate in this situation though.

Comment: Thanks, now it works. The second code you posted, the entire thing is going over my head, not able to understand anything about it. I will check the doc thoroughly before getting into it. Can you please explain what you meant by global namespace? And where can I get some info about namespaces of Extjs? I am very new and in a hurry to learn it for implementing some immidiate business needs, I have heard about the term namespace which is used in C++/C# but I have never used any of them :(

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have namespaces in the same capacity as other languages, but, every time you declare a variable outside of a function or object, it is attached to the window object.  Because all code shares this object, including frameworks, analytics packages, browser plugins, etc..., I and some others consider it best practice to avoid it as much as possible.  My approach is to declare a single object and include all function and variable declarations as properties of that object.  In my example, I was doing that by putting everything in the MyApp object via Ext.define().

Answer (score 2):

use loadData method to load data to your combobox.

```
yourCombo.store.loadData(obj.responsetext);
```

Comment: How will I define the JSONStore? i.e. what will be the value in the reader URL? Please let me know.

Comment: you should use Simplestore.. so no need to give reader url :)

Comment: I tried but something is missing. I have posted my latest code. Please let me know what am i missing.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use StateCombo because it is the name of class and not the object instance itself. Therefor the store cannot be accessed by the code `StateCombo.storeStates.`

Actually, if you want to access the store to load data, you can do it in two ways. First, because on creation store object you save it in storeStates variable, you can access it and use. storeStates is either global variable or is know by closure. So by writting the following clause you execute the required operation:

```
storeStates.loadData();
```

Another way is by accessing the combobox control and then getting its bound store. By accessing the control means not using the class name, but it's instance. In order to access the combobox control, you first have to modify your declaration of combobox and define instance name by setting itemId:

```
Ext.define('StateCombo', {

itemId: 'stateCombo',
extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
alias: 'widget.statecombo',
queryMode: 'local',
valueField: 'State',
displayField: 'State',
store: storeStates
});
```

Once the widget is known, it can be found by:

```
var arr = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('stateCombo');
```

Now, we can load data:

```
if (arr.length>0)
   arr[0].loadData();
```

Answer (score 1):

just a quick thought from edited post,
response is containing

`{"data":[{"state":"sanghai"},{"state":"state2"}]}` state in lowercase while in store it is defined as `fields: ['State']`

and another thing the ajax response is json string, so it should be decoded before calling the `loadData` method of store.

like `var response = Ext.decode(obj.responseText);`

then call loadData as `StateCombo.storeStates.loadData(response.data);`

Comment: Hi, I tried what you suggested. I am getting a error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'loadData' of undefined ` Any help???

Comment: try to log the store on select listener, are you able to access store or not. like `console.log(StateCombo.storeStates);`

Comment: when I try to log it in the console, it is printing `undefined`. But I dont know the reason for this. Any help on this?

Comment: you are not able to access combo store, try giving `itemId` to combo, & then try to access like `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('itemidofcombo')`,once you are abel to access combo store, try to call loadData.

Comment: When I try this: `console.log(Ext.ComponentQuery.query('stateComboId'));` then in the console I am getting `[]`. Again, when I try this: `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('stateComboId').loadData(response.data);` then I am getting the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'loadData'` What is the reason for this error?

Answer (score 1):

Let's see the example below of using two combobox controls bound to two different stores. Changing first combobox raises event which reload (in my example it do filters) the data accordingly to the selected value. Then the store of the second combobox is reloaded and the control refilled.

This example shows how both model, store and view are cooperate and used together. Generally it uses local data collection, but you can easily to configure the store and proxy so it will bring the data from the server side:

```
 // Set up a model to use in our Store
 Ext.define('Countries', {
     extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
     fields: [
         {name: 'abbr', type: 'string'},
         {name: 'name',  type: 'string'}
     ]
 });

// The data store containing the list of states
var countries = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    model: 'Countries', 
    data : [
        {"abbr":"US", "name":"United States"},
        {"abbr":"FR", "name":"France"}
        //...
    ]
});

 // Set up a model to use in our Store
 Ext.define('States', {
     extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
     fields: [
         {name: 'cntry', type: 'string'},
         {name: 'abbr', type: 'string'},
         {name: 'name',  type: 'string'}
     ]
 });

// The data store containing the list of states
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad: false,
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    model: 'States', 
    data : [
        {"cntry": "US", "abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
        {"cntry": "US", "abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
        {"cntry": "US", "abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"},
        {"cntry": "FR", "abbr":"PR", "name":"Paris"}
        //...
    ],
    listeners: {
        beforeload: function () {

        }
    }

});


// Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
var a = Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose Country',
    store: countries ,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'abbr',
    // Basically this code was tested on Simple Online ExtJS Code Editor
    // http://ext4all.com/post/simple-online-extjs-code-editor
    // so it was bounded to the codeoutput control 
    renderTo: 'codeoutput', 
    listeners: {
        // when we change the value of Countries combobox, this event is raised
        change: function(obj, newVal, oldVal, eOpts) {
            // we can also use states.filter() function in the same way
            states.filterBy ( function(record, id) {
            // newVal variable is available due to closure, so we can compare the row with the selected country and result appropriate notification
            if (record.get("cntry")==newVal) return true;
          });
        }
    }
});


// Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
var a = Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: states,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'abbr',
    renderTo: 'codeoutput'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the code posted above, it helped me conceptually. In the above code which I posted, it seems like the problem is with configuring the store and proxy only while fetching the data from the server in json format. Can you please let me know where is the problem? I am getting an erorr: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'loadData' of undefined`

Comment: Try to access the store directly. Because the state store is stored in the global variable storeStates, you can write storeStates.loadData(). Then check if states combobox was changed as the part of load. If it has no any affect, the problem is association between store and view.